# Add external js file in Inertia JS

Tags: laravel, inertiajs

im many time try and searching but i can’t fixed this bug , i need add my js file in inertia js and little time working little time not working
Im add js in app.php and app.js

App.js

```
import './bootstrap';
import './flowbite.min.js';
import '../css/app.css';
import '../css/flowbite.min.css';
```

App.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title inertia>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.bunny.net">
        <link href="https://fonts.bunny.net/css?family=figtree:400,500,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/1.7.0/flowbite.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!-- Scripts -->
        @routes
        @vite(['resources/js/app.js', "resources/js/Pages/{$page['component']}.vue"])
        @inertiaHead
    </head>
    <body class="font-sans antialiased">
        @inertia
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/1.7.0/flowbite.min.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Can help me many month im trying but not find answer
Thanks in advance

Sometimes working sometimes not working